# Haskell Convert numbers in a string into a type

Tags: haskell

I have defined a type as:

`type Register = Int`

I'm also able to read in a list of numbers from a list of Strings using a function like:

```
readInt :: String -> Int
readInt s = read s :: Int
```

now, using `readInt` on a list like `readInt "12 32 11"` gives me `[12, 32, 11]` which is of type `[Int]`.

My question is: instead of `[Int]`, how can I get `[Register]`.

I tried:

```
readRegister :: String -> Register
readRegister s = read s :: Register
```

but as I guessed, it doesn't seem to be valid syntax.

Comment: Works for me, this produces no error: http://hpaste.org/63762 - You should include the error you get from your code in your sample, plus any other code you have which relates to this

Comment: Type aliases in Haskell are very weak; they are pretty much interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `Register` is a type alias, i.e. it is interchangeable with its right hand side, i.e. here with `Int`.

But you state that `readInt "12 32 11"` would yield `[12,32,11] :: [Int]`. This is impossible given your type signature of `readInt :: String -> Int`. Perhaps you could show us a bit more of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more details. The readInt function is used as 

`map readInt (words s)`

Now my readRegister code is

    readRegister :: String -> Register
    readRegister s = read s :: Register
    readRegisters s :: String -> [Register]
    readRegisters s = map readRegister (words s)

Answer (score 2):

`Register` is just another name for the type `Int`, it is the same type. The syntax

```
readRegister :: String -> Register
readRegister s = read s :: Register
```

is valid (but the type annotation on the `read` result is unnecessary). If it doesn't work, your compiler/interpreter is broken. Whether the type is displayed as `Int` or `Register`, however, may be surprising. It's not easy to predict when a type synonym is expanded and when not.